# How to request refugee status/asylum in Qatar due to a threat in home country?

Tags: visa, working-visas, immigration, asylum

Due to threats in my home country, I ran away from my country. I went to Qatar on a tourist visa. But I need long-term shelter. I worked in politics in my home country.

**Can someone help me on writing this as a letter in meaningful way?**

Answer (score 3):

You may have a difficulty directly seeking asylum in Qatar. According to the [**United Nations High Commission on Refugees (UNHCR)**](http://www.refworld.org/pdfid/528345c24.pdf)

> The State of Qatar has not ratified either the 1951 Convention on the Status of Refugees or its 1967 Protocol (hereinafter jointly referred to as the 1951 Refugee Convention).
>
> Qatar has not adopted any national protection mechanisms for asylum-seekers and refugees.
>
> Qatar is not a State party to the 1954 Convention relating to the Status of Stateless Persons or the 1961 Convention on the Reduction of Statelessness.
>
> The functional responsibilities for all aspects related to refugee status determination in Qatar are carried out by UNHCR from its office in Saudi Arabia:

Address your request to:

The UNHCR Regional Representative in Saudi Arabia
P.O.Box 94003, 11693 Riyadh, Saudi Arabia
Telephone: 966 11 488 0049 Facsimile: 966 11 482 8737
Email: sauri@unhcr.org